# Is there any way by which we can communicate back to the class which generated an intent and sent it from a class which extends IntentService class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

While building my app I have a class( class A) which extends another class say class B. Now I create an intent from this class and pass this intent to another class C which in turn extends IntentService. Now, the question is : Is there any way by which I can communicate back with class A from class C.

```
class A extends B
{
    .
    .
    .
    void method1()
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, C.class);
         context.startService(intent);
     }

     void method2(String param)
     {
      .
      .
      .
     }
}
```

class C.java is as follows:

```
class C extends IntentService
{
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        // Need to call method2 of the same object from which intent was created in class A
        // What should be done?
    }
}
```

I hope I was able to explain the question properly. Please help me out with this. TIA

Comment: does B extend Activity?

Comment: @SimonMeier: No none of the classes extend Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with IntentService. But whenever I had another class to do something I returned its result through a LocalBroadcastManager, which means from class C you sent an intent back through the LocalBroadcastManager and receive it in A by registering to that broadcastet intent:

in C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("SERVICE_FINISHED");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in A:

```
    public A() {
      broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              if(intent.getAction().equals("SERVICE_FINISHED")) {
                //do stuff}
              }
          }
      };
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SERVICE_FINISHED"));
   }
```